# Admin SDK Reports API activities.watch() filter not working

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk

### What I want to do

I want to receive token events with push notifications, but I do not want to receive push notifications for a certain `unwanted_client_id`.

### My code

This is my code right now:

```
body = {
    'id': 'some_id',
    'token': 'some_random_token',
    'type': 'web_hook',
    'address': 'https://my.address.com/some/endpoint',
    'payload': 'true',
}

service.activities().watch(
    applicationName='token',
    userKey='all',
    filters='client_id<>unwanted_client_id',
    body=body
).execute()
```

### Problem

I start receiving the push notifications, but I'm also receiving them for the `unwanted_client_id`.

### Notes

I tested the exact same filter with `activities().list()` and there it works, i.e. I don't get the events for `unwanted_client_id`.